# ¿Cómo calcular el porcentaje de una cantidad de datos desconocido? PHP - Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un sistema de encuestas, y el problema ya está solucionado.

El problema era el siguiente:

No existe un numero definido de respuestas posibles para una pregunta, sino que existe un administrador que va ingresando las opciones en caso de que la persona que va respondiendo la encuesta no encuentre la opción que busca (esas opciones de respuesta vienen de otra tabla).

Pero en este caso, ya que no hay un número de posibles respuestas definidas, no sé cómo crear una variable que sustituya lo que está en siguiente código como 'Centro Escolar'. Tengo más o menos una idea de cómo (una función que haga un recorrido por la tabla 'alumno' para ver las diferentes opciones o un select) en este caso hice el select.

Mi objetivo es que al final el administrador pueda visualizar un porcentaje de las respuestas dadas por todos los usuarios sin importar la cantidad de opciones de respuesta.

Soy nueva programando, así que cualquier ayuda aún me es útil.

El código anterior es este:

```
// Crear conexion
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Comprobar conexion
    if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

//Calcular el total de encuestados
$query="SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM `alumno`";
$enc=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($enc);
        $total=$data['total'];
            //Consulta para CONTAR resultados de una opción de respuesta
            $contar="SELECT COUNT(institucion) AS ins FROM alumno WHERE institucion = 
                        (SELECT nombre_ins FROM instituto WHERE nombre_ins = 'Centro Escolar')";

            //Ejecutar consulta
            $resultados=mysqli_query($conn,$contar);
        $dataresult=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados);
    $institutos=$dataresult['ins'];
 //Si el resultado de la consulta es 0 que no haga nada
if ($institutos==0) {
echo "";
} else {

//Si la consulta != de cero se hace el cálculo de porcentaje
$perc=(($institutos/$total)*100);
    echo number_format($perc);
}
```

Y así quedó al final:

```
// Crear conexion
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Comprobar conexion
    if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    //Recorrer la tabla instituto
    $recorrer="SELECT * FROM instituto";
    $recorrido=$conn->query($recorrer);
    while ($fila=$recorrido->fetch_assoc()) {

        //Calcular el total de encuestados
        $query="SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM `alumno`";
            $enc=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                $data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($enc);
                    $total=$data['total'];
                        //Consulta para CONTAR resultados
                        $contar="SELECT COUNT(institucion) AS ins FROM alumno WHERE institucion = 
                                    (SELECT nombre_ins FROM instituto WHERE nombre_ins = '$fila[nombre_ins]')";

                        //Ejecutar consulta
                        $resultados=mysqli_query($conn,$contar);
                    $dataresult=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados);
                $institutos=$dataresult['ins'];
             //Si el resultado de la consulta es 0 que no haga nada
        if ($institutos==0) {
            echo "";
        } else {

            //Si la consulta != de cero se hace el cálculo de porcentaje
            $perc=(($institutos/$total)*100);
                echo number_format($perc);
        }
    }
```

Y cualquier otra sugerencia me será de mucha ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cual es el resultado que esperas?

Comment: Supongamos que 2 personas fueron encuestadas, y cada una tiene una opción de respuesta distinta. Es decir que al final debe decir 50 y 50. y la variable que da el porcentaje al final es $perc

Comment: ¿Cual es tu modelo de base de datos? Coloca las tablas. Necesitamos mas información para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Las tablas son: 'alumno' e 'instituto',
La tabla alumno un campo tipo varchar llamado 'institucion'. Y la tabla instituto tiene un id y un campo llamado nombre_ins de tipo varchar.
Estuve revisando mi código y llegué a la conclusión de que es más fácil hacer un select que abarque todo mi código anterior.
El problema ya lo solucioné, pero alguna otra opinión también sería bien recibida.

Comment: podrias hacer un solo query como `SELECT COUNT(institucion) as ins, nombre_ins  instituto FROM alumno 
group by nombre_ins ` y despues calcular con el for, incluso todo en el select pero podria ser mas complicado de entender